# Как при обновлении страницы перенаправлять пользователя на главную

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Нужно сделать так, чтобы пользователь при обновлении любой страницы ([www.website.com/pageOne;](http://www.website.com/pageOne;) [www.website.com/pageTwo](http://www.website.com/pageTwo)) оказывался на главной [www.website.com](http://www.website.com)
проект на react, навигация react-router-dom
На удивлении не нашел ничего толкового в поисковике

Comment: sessionStorage вам в помощь. Пользователь попал на главную, положите туда флаг какой нибудь. А на других страницах проверяйте, существует ли он, если нет, то делайте редирект(можно прям window.location в useEffect)

Comment: а как проверять это именно при обновлении страницы?

Comment: Проверять всегда. Просто при обновлении страницы sessionStorage удалится. Еще вариант в каком нибудь начальном компоненте, который гарантированно ставится один раз всегда делать принудительный редирект силами react-router

Comment: вам необходимо написать свой `middleware` и в нём производить логику редиректа в зависимости от требуемого условия

Comment: их можно писать на клиентской части приложения, или только бек?